# How to find most connected child nodes in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

So I'm new to OrientDB, and while I'm pretty good at SQL the syntax to get what I want in OrientDB is escaping me.

I know I can do something like `select *, in().size() as size from Users order by size desc` to find the most connected node of a certain class (Users in this case), but how do I find the most connected children a couple levels down?

I.e., let's say I have Organizations --> PROMOTES (edge) --> Platform --> MANAGES (edge) --> Suggestion

How do I find the most connected *Suggestions* at the *Organization* level? I.e., I know I can easily find the most connected suggestions one level out using the query I shared, but what about the most connected another level beyond that?

I'd ultimately like a result which lists each Suggestion along with how indirectly connected (number of edges) it is to Organizations.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### Use `TRAVERSE`

You should use the command `TRAVERSE` to do that

```
SELECT out(PROMOTES).size() AS connectedOrg,* 
FROM (
    TRAVERSE out(MANAGES) 
    FROM Suggestion WHILE $depth < 2
)
WHERE $depth > 0
```

Result will be the *Platforms* linked to a *Suggestion*. Records can be duplicated.
Along with each *Platform*, you get the number of *Organisation* called `connectedOrg`.

**About traverse :**
Traverse follow the record ids present in a record and aggregates them in the results. With `WHILE $depth < 2` you can limit search to only one level and with `WHERE $depth > 0` you can remove the original record from the result. [More info here](https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/sql/SQL-Traverse.html).

### Use OrientDB Functions

If you need to know how many *Organization* is linked to each *Suggestion* (through *Plateform*), use this syntax.

```
SELECT *, set(out(MANAGES).out(PROMOTES), null).size() FROM Suggestion
```

Note : `, null` allows to switch from `AGGREGATE` to `INLINE`. It prevents from having all sizes aggregated in a single record. See [the doc](https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/sql/SQL-Functions.html#inline-mode) for more info.

Comment: Ah, this was helpful and it works to the degree that I get a connectedOrg count at the `Platform` level--but my attempts to get the connectedOrg count at the `Suggestion` level haven't yielded any results. I've tried: `SELECT out(PROMOTES).size() AS connectedOrg,* FROM ( TRAVERSE IN(MANAGES) FROM Suggestion WHILE $depth < 2 ) WHERE $depth > 0 ORDER BY connectedOrg desc` but that just gives me connectedOrg count at the Platform level, where I'm really trying to get to the Suggestion level. Any tips on how this can be done?

Comment: Ideally I'd get a list of suggestions and associated connectedOrg count (number of organizations connected (indirectly) to a suggestion)

Comment: Also, for my education, it'd be super helpful if you'd explain what in the heck this query is doing. I gather that somehow it's gathering/grouping everything together so at the SELECT level I can use `size()` to get the count of those edge connections, but beyond that I don't get it

Comment: I have completed my question according to your comments ;)